# Error when uploading images using NSURLConnection

Tags: php, objective-c, post

I am attempting to upload images using NSURLConnection and the POST method here is what I have so far.

```
  NSData* imageData =UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageView.image, 90);
NSString  * urlString =@"mywebiste.myphpfile.php";
NSMutableURLRequest * request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary=@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData * returnData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(returnString);
```

here is the php file that I am calling

```
<?PHP

    $uploaddir = './';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    $uploadFile = $file;
    $randomNumber = rand(0, 99999);
    $newName = $uploadDir . $randomNumber . $uploadFile;


    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
        echo "Temp file uploaded. \r\n";
    } else {
        echo "Temp file not uploaded. \r\n";
    }

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']> 300000) exit("Your file is too large.");
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $newName)) {
        $postsize = ini_get('post_max_size');   //Not necessary, I was using these
        $canupload = ini_get('file_uploads');    //server variables to see what was
        $tempdir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');   //going wrong.
        $maxsize = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
        echo "http://www.mywebsite.com/{$file}" . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] . "\r\n" . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] ;
    }

?>
```

The error I get from this is a bit unspecific.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
webmaster@mywebsite.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

has this ever happened to anyone before and is there any way to fix it?
I need to figure this out and I don't know where to go from here. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should check your server error log, to find the specific PHP error that triggered the 500 HTTP response. BTW, check your variable `$uploaddir`, your are calling it `$uploadDir` when you reference it.

Comment: Thanks but I already checked the error logs and its empty